# Using an Angular 2 http.post without subscribing? Or am I thinking of it wrong?

Tags: angular, http-post, observable, angular2-services

**Is there a way to just tell the server to update data without subscribing? Skipping a return statement and a subscription seems to render the http call inert.**

In my case, my DB guy created a bunch of stored procedures that return nothing and sometimes I want to do something simple like this in my service:

```
public setItem(item: IRequestItem) {
        this.http.post('api/items', item);
    }
```

and call it like this in my component:

```
save() {
        var comp = this;
        this.items.forEach(function(item) {
            comp.service.setItem(item)
        });
    }
```

Instead I have to do something like this in the service:

```
public setItem(item: IRequestItem) {
        return this.http.post('api/items', item);
    }
```

And then call it like this in the conponent:

```
save() {
        var comp = this;
        this.items.forEach(function(item) {
            comp.service.setItem(item).subscribe(r => console.log(r));
        });
    }
```

Which would return lots of these:

```
Response {_body: "", status: 204, ok: true, statusText: "No Content", headers: Headers…}
_body : ""
headers : Headers
ok : true
status : 204
statusText : "No Content"
type : 2
url : "http://localhost:56018/api/items"
__proto__ : Object
```

I'm just learning so maybe I'm looking at it wrong. Can I interpret something in that Response object that will let me know if the operation failed or succeeded? Or is there another syntax that will just return a success or failure instead of the confusing "No Content" response?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular http.post without .subscribe callback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41296052/angular-http-post-without-subscribe-callback)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to trigger the request, you need to call `subscribe` but you do not need to return the request observable from the service and call it from the component, you can call subscribe from within the service.

```
setItem(item: RequestItem) {
  this.http.post('api/items', item)
    .subscribe({ error: e => console.error(e) });
}
```

Now in the above, the service will immediately return, *before* the request completes but the request will be made and any errors logged from within the service.

Answer (score 0):

The `Observable` returned by `http.post` is a "cold" observable: it won't do anything unless someone subscribes to it.

In RXJS 7 you can turn such cold observable into "hot"/connectable observable using `ReplaySubject` and `connectable`. If someone subscribes to it, it will get the result. If nobody subscribes to it, it'll still be invoked. Add this utility function into your code:

```js
  private wrapObservable<T>(coldObservable: Observable<T>): Observable<T> {
    const observable = connectable(
      coldObservable,
      {
        connector: () => new ReplaySubject<T>(),
        resetOnDisconnect: false
      }
    );
    observable.connect();
    return observable;
  }
```

Then wrap `http.post` with it:

```js
public setItem(item: IRequestItem): Observable<IItemSetResult> {
    return this.wrapObservable(this.http.post('api/items', item));
}
```

Now you can call `setItem` without `.subscribe()` - it'll work:

```js
save() {
    var comp = this;
    this.items.forEach(function(item) {
        comp.service.setItem(item);
    });
}
```

If you need the results, you can subscribe to the wrapped observable:

```js
save() {
    var comp = this;
    this.items.forEach(function(item) {
        comp.service.setItem(item)
            .subscribe(itemSetResult =>
                console.log(`Server returned result: ${itemSetResult}`)
            );
    });
}
```