# Angular http.post without .subscribe callback

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

I'm wondering if I can make just a http **post request without subscribing on callbacks**, something like this

```
 this._http.post('/list/items/update?itemId=' + itemId + "&done=" + done, null);
```

instead of this

```
 this._http.post('/list/items/update?itemId=' + itemId + "&done=" + done, null)
        .subscribe();
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I do not think you can.

http.post (and get, put, delete, etc) returns a cold Observable, i.e. an Observable for which:

> its underlying producer is created and activated during subscription

[Source](https://medium.com/@benlesh/hot-vs-cold-observables-f8094ed53339#.tofgfsou4).

This means the function represented by the `Observable` is activated only with the `subscribe()` method.

Convenience methods subscribe too, see implementation details for `Observable#toPromise()` [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/e06a472979ed29e163ad095db0125b2d82bec2f0/src/internal/Observable.ts#L474).

Comment: That question should be deleted or extended, since right now it is misleading. `2oppin` has showed below that you actually can do it, so the statement `I do not think you can.` is wrong.

Comment: @Sasuke Uchiha I think that `toPromise` actually subscribes to the Observable in [its implementation](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.5.5/src/internal/Observable.ts#L12-L363)

Comment: That is a very good catch. Could you, please, add it in your answer?

Answer (score 12):

I'm using conversion to Promise (requires rxjs):

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
@Injectable()
export class SomeService {
....
  post(sp: Seatplace, date?: Date) : Promise<any> {
     return this.http.post(
       '/list/items/update?itemId=' + itemId + "&done=" + done, 
        null
     ).toPromise();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I had the same question but then I figured out that I actually don't care if someone subscribes to the observable. I just want the POST request sent in any case. This is what I came up with:

```
postItem(itemData) {
    var observable = this.http.post('/api/items', itemData)
        .map(response => response.json()) // in case you care about returned json       
        .publishReplay(); // would be .publish().replay() in RxJS < v5 I guess
    observable.connect();
    return observable;
}
```

The request is sent as soon as `connect()` is called. However, there is still an observable that the caller of `postItem` can subscribe to if required. Since `publishReplay()` is used instead of just `publish()`, subscribing is possible even after the POST request completed.

Comment: This throws `error TS2339: Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object'.`

Comment: If someone else wants to use this approach with RxJS 6, you will have to cast the `Observable` to connect it:

`const observable = this.http.post<T>('/api/items', itemData).pipe(publishReplay()); (observable as ConnectedObservable<T>).connect(); return observable;`

Comment: @kremerd ConnectableObservable not Connected... thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Just like @picci points, regular observables are cold observables. If you want to make the request you can try @lex82 idea, here is a rxjs 6 draft:

```
import { ConnectableObservable } from "rxjs"
import { publish } from "rxjs/operators";

const myConnectableObservable: ConnectableObservable<any> = this._http.post('/list/items/update?itemId=' + itemId + "&done=" + done, null).pipe(publish()) as ConnectableObservable<any>;
myConnectableObservable.connect();
```

which basically is like a subscribe but without to make a real subscription.

https://blog.danlew.net/2018/09/25/connectable-observables-so-hot-right-now/

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use toPromise method like below:

```
public getEmployerListFromService() {
    const url = `/list/items/update?itemId=`;
    return this.http.get<any>(url).toPromise().then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    })
  }
```

And Call this method by :

```
 this.service.getEmployerListFromService();
```