# HTTP Response in Angular gives 200 but never reached server

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, ngxs

We have a webapplication done in Angular 6 which makes use of NGXS for State Management.

We have one particular call to our server where we have problems with. All other calls with almost the same code have no problems. On our dev environments this works without any problem.

Both our server environment and our local dev environment use the same database.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpY2h.png (I do not have enough reputation to post images, sorry)

As you can see in the response here, the url is empty, all the test params are no part of the response.

Server logging, seems like it never reaches the controller, nor it has an exception.
Fiddler, it never shows it is communicating with the API.

```js
protected getEntities(viewContext: ViewContext, entityQuery: TEntityQuery, pagingContext: PagingContext): Observable<QueryResult<TEntity[]>> {

    const params = this.requestUtilsService.getHttpParams(entityQuery, viewContext, pagingContext);

    this.logger.log('sending entity query with params', params);

    const entitiesUrl = this.getEntitiesUrl();

    return this.http.get<TEntity[]>(entitiesUrl, { params: params, observe: 'response' }).pipe(
      map(resp => this.responseUtilsService.getQueryResult(resp))
    );
  }
```

I expect a list of entities or a server error. I expect the typescript code to contact the API.

Comment: what do you have for `this.getEntitiesUrl()`?

Comment: can you try adding a subscribe to the http.get request in angular? similar to here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41296052/angular-http-post-without-subscribe-callback

Comment: I have tried to add a manual subscribe to it, gives the same result. We are using NGXS and that should automatically use a subscribe(). Also, it comes with a HTTPREsult, which indicates a subscribe has been done?

Comment: this.getEntitiesUrl() just generates the URL based on the controller to contact.

Comment: getQueryResult() doesn't do anything regarding the request/response, it just creates an object from the array given by the Response and some headers (paging)

Comment: @DanielBennekers I cannot reproduce but I can suggest that you look that entitiesUrl is indeed correct and matches the backend, also that a subscribe is done after the map and maybe the return type does not need QueryResult? Or then the get request also needs <QueryResult<TEntity[]>>.

Comment: @Davelis4 thank you so much for your help. As you can see this is a generic function which we use for multiple calls. For the url that we are having problems it has been working  and for all other calls it works without problems. Also, I'd expect an error if the url is wrong?
If I use the url in Postman, it works without any problems.

Comment: @DanielBennekers did you solve it yet?

Comment: Hello @Davelis4, yes I have managed to fix the problem, I have posted the solution below! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have managed to solve the problem and I'd like to share the solution:

We were using a Controller on the backend called AssetsController, somehow all requests to this name were never sent and still got a HTTP 200 response. When we changed the name of the controller, everything worked as it should.

The exact reason why it did not work is unknown, but we are happy we could solve this.

Thanks to everybody who has been helping me!

Yours sincerely,

Daniel

Answer (score -1):

Do you add subscription to the http.get()? Rxjs Observables are lazy in the sense that they only execute values when something subscribes to it. They don't execute request until get subscription.

From https://angular.io/guide/http:
"An HttpClient method does not begin its HTTP request until you call subscribe() on the observable returned by that method"

Comment: I have tried to add a manual subscribe to it, gives the same result. We are using NGXS and that should automatically use a subscribe(). Also, it comes with a HTTPREsult, which indicates a subscribe has been done?