# How to check Observable if data exist in Angular 8

Tags: angular, reactive-programming, angular-reactive-forms, rxjs6

I'm trying to implement a CRUD functionality in a reactive programming way. I have a form where one of it's field `identifier_name` must be unique.

But, before calling the create new or update method, I need to check first if the value of `identifier_name` field that I'm creating or updating is already exists in the observable where my observable is like this.

```
this.userService.users$;
```

Below is my code in my component.

```
@Component({...})
    export class UserEditComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

        subscription: Subscription = new Subscription();

        ngOnDestroy() {
          this.subscription.unsubscribe();
        }

        saveUser(): void {
            if (this.userForm.valid) {
                this.identifierExists$.subscribe(exists => {
                      if (exists) {
                        this.snackBar.open('The scope identifier must be unique.', 'Close', { duration: 5000 });
                      } else {
                        if (this.isNewRecord) {
                            this.createNewUser();
                        } else {
                            this.updateUser();
                        }
                      }
                    })          
            } else {
                this.snackBar.open("An error occured while saving your changes. Please try again.", "Close", { duration: 5000 });
            }
        }

      createNewUser(): void {
        this.subscription.add(
          this.userService.saveUser(this.userForm.value)
            .pipe(catchError(this.handleError))
            .subscribe(() => {
              this.snackBar.open('New user successfully created.', 'Close', { duration: 5000 });
            })
        )
      }

      updateUser(): void {
        this.subscription.add(
          this.userService.selectedUserIdAction$
            .pipe(
              switchMap(id => this.userService.updateUser(id, this.userForm.value))
            )
            .subscribe(_ => {
              this.snackBar.open("User successfully updated.", "Close", { duration: 5000 })
            })
        )
      }

    }
```

What I have in mind is to do like this.

```
    private identifierSubject = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
    identifierAction$ = this.identifierSubject.asObservable();

    identifierExists$ = this.identifierAction$.pipe(
            switchMap(identifier => {
                this.userService.users$
                    .pipe(
                        map(users => users.some(user => user.identifier_name === identifier))
                    )
            })
        )
```

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to achieve my requirement as I'm very new in the concept of reactive programming.

Additionally, if you noticed my 2 methods `createNewUser()` and `updateUser`. Is there a way I can trigger the **create** and **update** without subscribing? What I know in reactive programming was to avoid the `subscribe`. But, not really sure how to do this the right way.

Hope you can guide me on how to properly do this in a reactive programming way.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

1. You say you have a form and you want a value to be unique. I highly recommend that you don't do this check when pressing on saveUser(). Rather use validators, as a result the form won't be valid until you have a unique name. Reactive forms serve both - sync and async - validators.
2. Are you aware, that you add a subscription to your component with every submit click?
3. I have trouble to understand why your identifier is stored within a BehaviorSubject. Isn't that too much?

Regarding your create+update check out this post: [Angular http.post without .subscribe callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41296052/angular-http-post-without-subscribe-callback)

Comment: hey @MoxxiManagarm. Thanks for your comment. I'll give it a try #1 sugestion. For #2, yes I'm aware that I'm adding a subscription on the create and update method for me to unsubscribe `onDestroy`.  I updated my post to include this. For the #3, I'm watching the value of `identifier_name` using the `BehaviorSubject` so I can search it to my list of users using `switchMap`. I know this might be ugly and not usual, but I'm very happy for better suggestions. Cheers!

Comment: Just an update here. I have implemented the custom validators and it works. But, the next challenge is that, I need the old value of `identifier_name` for some extra checking like, if the current selected `identifier_name` is equal to the new value of the control, then I should not flag this as an existing record.